# Rails validation required parameter (lock_version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question about how can I validate a required change at rails model.

for example:

to the param lock_version we need the validate if this value always is present when tried to update the model.

has rails some validation to test the change presence?

Thanks

Comment: You should watch [Railscasts Optimistic Locking](http://railscasts.com/episodes/59-optimistic-locking)

Answer (score 0):

This type of validation is handled by `validates_presence_of`.

Seems like you're looking for

`validates_presence_of :lock_version, on: :update`

I strongly advise to take a look on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of

There are plenty of validations in Rails and this is probably the most basic one.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: hmm, I don't think so, I need to validate if always :lock_version is present. 

for example:

if user sent it nil, validates_presence_of will add an error, but if user doesn't sent it, active record will update, and I need to add an error even parameters is not present

Comment: Not sure what you mean but if you want the validator to work on both create and update just remove the `on: :update` param and if you want to validate that the value is not nil then add `allow_nil: false` param

Answer (score 0):

@jakub is right, however if you want another way of validating fields you can use html validations. Add `required: true` to any field you need to be filled out. I.e

`<%= f.text_field :lock_version, required: true %>`

If a user tries to submit the form without this field they will get a flash message pop up over the field telling them to fill it out.

Justin

Comment: for example: 

in a model User
    `validates_presence_of :lock_version`. 

On rails console when I run

`User.first.update!({})`

it works, but I need that attribute  :lock_version is required